# SQL Hangs on FTP Command but works off Command Line

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ftp, xp-cmdshell

SQL hangs on this command:

```
     EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'ftp -s:C:\FTP\connect'
```

But doesn't hang on any other command I've tried using `xp_cmdshell` like `echo` `open` `get` and it works just fine, so I know the permissions for SQL Server to the Folder (and Download folder) are set properly.

...And when `ftp -s:C:\FTP\connect` is executed on the command line, the FTP transfer begins, and completes successfully.

The SQL command that is giving issues on this particular server, worked completely fine on my other server.  I'm really not sure what else needs to be done.  Does anyone know why SQL hangs when I execute an FTP command besides anything else I've been through?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably Server firewall is blocking the command for the port you are running in the first instance (which might get byspassed using the commandline)